# PHP date() returns time wrong

Tags: php, date, time

When using PHP to do time() and store it in a MySQL server and then retrieve it,
when I try to convert it into seconds, it returns strange results.

1386787112 = 35 seconds ago (What my PHP says)

1386787112 was actually 1 second ago (What my current time says).

```
$da = date("s",1386787112);
```

This code is meant to returns the current time in second but it only updates if the time is bigger than 60 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your PHP server and MySQL server have the same time?

Comment: You've shown absolutely no code that would output "35 seconds ago"

Comment: Huh? `date('i')` returns the *minute* portion of the timestamp. In no way does it mean "seconds ago".

Comment: h2ooooooooo, date("i",1386787112); shows 35 seconds ago even though it should show 1 second ago. qwertynl, PHP is the one that does time()...

Comment: `i` does not do what you think it does. Please RTFM.

Comment: I copied the wrong code, I've now fixed the code to the correct line.

Comment: @KeirDavis `date("s")` shows the seconds. `10:25:20` would return `20`. `13:37:07` would return `07`. Here's the [manual](http://www.php.net/date) that **very** clearly explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`time()`](http://www.php.net/time) function will do what you're looking for. It's in fact defined just like your requirements.

Now, if you wanted `seconds ago` you could then use the `time()` function to do that:

```
$secs = time() - dbTimeValOfRecord;
```

Comment: Thankyou, you fixed my problem even with all the negative feedback from the others :)

Comment: @KeirDavis, I'm glad I could be of assistance.